# Get parent count that has a child with where condition

Tags: c#, linq, expression

```
        var totalParentsWithThisChild =
            (from p in parent
             from c in parent.Child
             where c.someField > someValue
             select parent
            ).Count();
```

this seems to get me childs that have someFiled > somevalue,

I like to count the parents that have a child where someField > someValue, how I can do it?

Comment: what is `gar` in your query?

Comment: sorry, I changed names to parent and child on my query to ask this and leave my parent "gar" variable that I use on my code. sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to check if there is children which matches given condition. And you can use [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx) with predicate to find count of parents which have such children:

```
parent.Count(p => p.Child.Any(c => c.someFiled > someValue))
```

Note: I suggest you to use names in plural form for collections: parents, children

---

*Slightly* query syntax:

```
var totalParentsWithThisChild = 
     (from p in parent
      where p.Child.Any(c => c.someFiled > someValue)
      select p).Count()
```

because there is no support for `Any` and `Count` extension methods in query syntax. To avoid ugly parentheses you can split this query in two parts:

```
var parentsWithThisChild = 
      from p in parent
      where p.Child.Any(c => c.someFiled > someValue)
      select p;

var totalParentsWithThisChild = parentsWithThisChild.Count();
```

but again, pure method syntax is much shorter in this case.

Comment: cool, there is a way using query expression? btw using parent.Count is enough, only to know about it

Comment: cool, using "Child.Any" was the thing that I not see before. I was sure that I was not seeing something that is simple but I cannot see. thanks you so much!